# how can I make $ work in wordpress for jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a plugin I want to use, but it depends on the $ identifier, as apposed to using jQuery.

Is it possible to enable the $, to save me recoding the plugin?

**EDIT**

The plugin automatically adds the javascript, therefore I can't wrap it.

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest using a different plugin, then. Or at least forking that plugin and rewriting the javascript to actually work with WordPress.

Comment: Also, if you could add a link to the plugin, we could maybe give you advice on the easiest way to hack the plugin to work correctly.

Comment: Is there not just a way to use $ in wordpress?

Comment: de-register jquery and then re-register your own copy without noConflict mode. You risk breaking a lot if you do that, though.

Comment: What would break?

Comment: As long as you kept the version of jQuery you're using identical to the one WordPress uses, you shouldn't have any problems. For example, using jQuery 1.5.x in WP 3.1 breaks almost everything in the admin area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery 
           Call your plugin here
       */
})
```

I think you already know this. But still for reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Also you can try `var $ = jQuery;` in the first line of the plugin. Sometime when i need to change all instance of $ to jQuery in a function. i just use it in the first line of the function and it works for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work, I believe:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: placed anywhere?

Comment: Placed above where you want to use $

Answer (score 1):

The code Sisir provided would work, or you can use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // you can use $ here
});
```